# PHPixie: в шаблон страницы подключить результаты вывода другого

Tags: php, phpixie

Проект на движке PHPixie.

Есть простой процессор `ProductCategories`, который выводит список категорий:

```
<?php

namespace Project\App\HTTP;

use PHPixie\HTTP\Request;

/**
 * Show product categories list
 */
class ProductCategories extends Processor
{
    /**
     * Default action
     * @param Request $request HTTP request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function defaultAction($request)
    {
        $components = $this->components();

        $product_categories = $components->orm()->query('product_category')
            ->orderAscendingBy('id')
            ->find();

        return $components->template()->get('app:productCategories', [
            'product_categories' => $product_categories
        ]);
    }
}
```

Отрабатывает нормально, если зайти на страницу http://localhost/productCategories

Однако нужно теперь подключить этот блок ещё раз на другой странице (на заглавной).

Пробую подключить в шаблоне главной:

```
<?php include $this->resolve('app:productCategories'); ?>
```

Однако выдаёт ошибку:

> Undefined variable: product_categories
>
> /www/vvvvvv/bundles/app/assets/templates/productCategories.php:6
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>     <h2>Категории продуктов</h2>
>     <?php foreach($product_categories as $product_category): ?>
>         <h3><?=$_($product_category->name)?></h3>
>         <div><a href="/product?id=<?=$_($product_category->id)?>"><?=$_($product_category->name)?></a></div>
>     <?php endforeach; ?>
> </div>
> ```

Как подключить правильно?

Answer (score 1):

По результатам обсуждения с sobolevna в чате PHPixie пришёл к следующему варианту:

В коде процессора `ProductCategories` явно выделил метод получения всех продуктов (для того, чтобы можно было вызвать его из другого процессора):

```
public function defaultAction($request)
{
    $components = $this->components();

    $product_categories = $this->getAllProductCategories();

    return $components->template()->get('app:productCategories', [
        'product_categories' => $product_categories
    ]);
}
public function getAllProductCategories()
{
    $components = $this->components();

    return $components->orm()->query('product_category')
        ->orderAscendingBy('id')
        ->find();
}
```

Процессор `StartPage` переделал. Было:

```
public function defaultAction($request)
{
    $template = $this->components()->template();
    $container = $template->get('app:startPage');
    return $container;
}
```

Стало:

```
public function defaultAction($request)
{
    $components = $this->components();

    $product_categories = $this->builder->httpProcessor()->processor('productCategories')->getAllProductCategories();

    return $components->template()->get('app:startPage', [
        'product_categories' => $product_categories
    ]);
}
```

И теперь подключение в шаблоне заглавной работает без ошибок:

```
<?php include $this->resolve('app:productCategories'); ?>
```

Если у кого-то есть более правильный способ с точки зрения фреймворка -- предлагайте альтернативно.